# How to handle the response redirection in REST APIs?

Tags: java, rest, api

REST APIs usually provides the response in a standard format. What if the endpoint of REST API has a case to redirect to another page (example: JSP page).

How to handle these case in REST API?

Answer (score 0):

> How to handle these case in REST API?

How would you do it on the web?

Typically, in two parts; a response payload, with content to explain to the user that there is some other resource of interest ("You should visit this resource"), and standardized meta-data in the headers, so that general purpose components can understand what is going on.

A REST API works the same way, with more care in the payload so that it is machine readable.